# How can I use JDK packages in Unit tests in Android project?

Tags: java, android, junit

My project is an Android library, so naturally I have `plugins { id 'com.android.library' }` in my `build.gradle`. This has unexpected effect that in unit tests imports like `import java.net.http.HttpClient;` cannot be resolved...

[image: compiler errors]

Indeed, I am aware that Android platform includes not even nearly all JDK classes, especially those found in newer JDKs.

But that applies only to the code which runs in Android, doesn't it? A *unit test* which runs on my host machine (i.e. not in Android but in the JDK) - why would it not see `java.net.http.HttpClient` of my host JDK? I assume that the compiler error I'm getting is result of a misconfiguration in Gradle.

I want to use such JDK classes in my unit tests. Is there a magic line in Gradle that I miss?